# Calculating $det(C^{-1}BAC)$ given det(A) and det(B).

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that A and B are two 2×2 matrices with det(A) = 3 and det(B) = 5. Compute:

$det(C^{-1}BAC)$, where C is an invertible 2 × 2 matrix with unknown determinant.

I assume that I don't have enough information to compute. Is this true? Or am I allowed to swap the order so I can cancel $C^{-1}C$.

Answer (score 2):

$det (AB)=\det (A) \det (B)$ and $det C^{-1}=\frac 1  {\det (C)}$. Hence the answer is $\det (A) \det (B)=15$.

[ $\det (C^{-1} BAC)=\det (C^{-1}) \det (BAC) =\det (C^{-1}) \det (B) \det (A) \det C$ and $\det (C^{-1}) \det C=1$.

Comment: So I am allowed to change the order of the determinant, which would give me det(BA) = det(B)det(A)?

Comment: @AngelaE I have added an explanation.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

assume the fact that a determinant function is a homomorphism from the multiplicative monoid of square matrices of a particular size to the scalar field from which the matrix entries are taken. that is:
$$
\det AB = \det A \det B 
$$
and

$$\det I = 1
$$

since the scalar field is commutative $ \det AB = \det BA $. in particular, if $C$ is an invertible matrix, then $\det CC^{-1} = \det I = 1$.

so: $\det C^{-1}ABC = \det C^{-1}CAB = \det IAB = \det AB $